# How do I upload files to S3 instead of my hard drive using PyroCMS 2.1.5?

Tags: content-management-system, amazon-s3, pyrocms, pyro

I can't seem to figure out how to post files (images, etc) to amazon S3.

I'd like for this to be default behavior for ALL media upload areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jerel Unruh put together a video all about this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Te61OzHK400

Really you just enter your Amazon credentials into the settings area, then hook a folder up with the bucket. All images will be sent to S3 and cached locally, and work identically to local files.